# On Handsontable, if there is similar columns header, then the first columns cell value is auto copied to other similar cell

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, handsontable

Whenever I enter a value in the first cell, then the same value is auto copied to the same name header cell. How can we stop this? I tried to google this issue but didn't found any suitable solution.

Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function (res)
    {
        grid = new Handsontable(container, {
            data: [],
            rowHeaders: true,
            autowidth: false,
            autoRowSize:true,
            maxRows: 100,
            minRows: 15,
            width: 'auto',
            height: 420,
            stretchH: 'all', //this is used to cover the full div
            overflow: 'hidden',

        colHeaders: res.data.header,
            columns: res.data.renderer,
            fillHandle: {
                autoInsertRow: false
            },
        minSpareRows: 1,               
        });        
    }
});
```

[image]

**Update**
Here is the json used for creating headers and list

```html
<iframe src="https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/ind7Savd" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you post the data response?

Comment: what if you change the header name? like multiline 1 and multiline 2 !

Comment: @AhmadHajjar its working fine if i change the header name. But it need to be same.

Comment: @jd_7 There is no post response. Am getting this duplication on filling the sheet.

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena can you post `res.data.header` and `res.data.renderer`?

Comment: Headers can have a same name, I guess you have same data value in columns https://jsfiddle.net/fuobfe3L

Comment: issue with your data or your having same data for those 2 columns.....try to provide your input data

Comment: @Saeed.Gh Yeah...It need to be same...the real problem is both values will have to different from each.

Comment: Could you please share the full script to better understand the problem?

Comment: SudhanshuSaxena I think what @Saeed.Gh conveyed is correct. If you think it is not correct then do post your sample data so that we get to know why his implementation is wrong.

Comment: @jd_7  posted the json used

Comment: the iframe returns an error: `ERROR, PASTE ID IS INVALID, OR PASTE HAS BEEN REMOVED!` please send the proper data... anyways, I think the problem is, that a javascript object can not contain the same key twice... so you need to do some kind of mapping to get it working... hard to tell without the data model though

Comment: @Argee thanks for your concern but now it's solved outside of stack overfly

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena please post here the answer for all community

Answer (score 1):

headers can contain `duplicate` same name column but because `JSON` object `{}` cannot contain duplicate keys we can assign data to different key and use it under same header name

```
var dataObject = [
  {
    id: 1,
    flag: 'EUR',
    currencyCode: 'EUR',
    currency: 'Euro',
    level: 0.9033,
    units: 'EUR / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '01',
    date2: 'date01',
    onedChng: 0.0026
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    flag: 'JPY',
    currencyCode: 'JPY',
    currency: 'Japanese Yen',
    level: 124.3870,
    units: 'JPY / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '02',
    date2: 'date02',
    onedChng: 0.0001
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    flag: 'GBP',
    currencyCode: 'GBP',
    currency: 'Pound Sterling',
    level: 0.6396,
    units: 'GBP / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '03',
    date2: 'date03',
    onedChng: 0.00
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    flag: 'CHF',
    currencyCode: 'CHF',
    currency: 'Swiss Franc',
    level: 0.9775,
    units: 'CHF / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '04',
    date2: 'date04',
    onedChng: 0.0008
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    flag: 'CAD',
    currencyCode: 'CAD',
    currency: 'Canadian Dollar',
    level: 1.3097,
    units: 'CAD / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '05',
    date2: 'date05',
    onedChng: -0.0005
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    flag: 'AUD',
    currencyCode: 'AUD',
    currency: 'Australian Dollar',
    level: 1.3589,
    units: 'AUD / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '05',
    date2: 'date05',
    onedChng: 0.0020
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    flag: 'NZD',
    currencyCode: 'NZD',
    currency: 'New Zealand Dollar',
    level: 1.5218,
    units: 'NZD / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '06',
    date2: 'date06',
    onedChng: -0.0036
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    flag: 'SEK',
    currencyCode: 'SEK',
    currency: 'Swedish Krona',
    level: 8.5280,
    units: 'SEK / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '07',
    date2: 'date07',
    onedChng: 0.0016
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    flag: 'NOK',
    currencyCode: 'NOK',
    currency: 'Norwegian Krone',
    level: 8.2433,
    units: 'NOK / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '08',
    date2: 'date08',
    onedChng: 0.0008
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    flag: 'BRL',
    currencyCode: 'BRL',
    currency: 'Brazilian Real',
    level: 3.4806,
    units: 'BRL / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '09',
    date2: 'date09',
    onedChng: -0.0009
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    flag: 'CNY',
    currencyCode: 'CNY',
    currency: 'Chinese Yuan',
    level: 6.3961,
    units: 'CNY / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '10',
    date2: 'date10',
    onedChng: 0.0004
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    flag: 'RUB',
    currencyCode: 'RUB',
    currency: 'Russian Rouble',
    level: 65.5980,
    units: 'RUB / USD',
    asOf: '08/19/2019',
    date1: '11',
    date2: 'date11',
    onedChng: 0.0059
  },
];
var currencyCodes = ['EUR', 'JPY', 'GBP', 'CHF', 'CAD', 'AUD', 'NZD', 'SEK', 'NOK', 'BRL', 'CNY', 'RUB', 'INR', 'TRY', 'THB', 'IDR', 'MYR', 'MXN', 'ARS', 'DKK', 'ILS', 'PHP'];
var flagRenderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  var currencyCode = value;
  while (td.firstChild) {
    td.removeChild(td.firstChild);
  }
  if (currencyCodes.indexOf(currencyCode) > -1) {
    var flagElement = document.createElement('DIV');
    flagElement.className = 'flag ' + currencyCode.toLowerCase();
    td.appendChild(flagElement);
  } else {
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(value === null ? '' : value);

    td.appendChild(textNode);
  }
};
var hotElement = document.querySelector('#hot');
var hotElementContainer = hotElement.parentNode;
var hotSettings = {
  data: dataObject,
  columns: [
    {
      data: 'id',
      type: 'numeric',
      width: 40
    },
    {
      data: 'flag',
            renderer: flagRenderer
    },
    {
      data: 'currencyCode',
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      data: 'currency',
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      data: 'level',
      type: 'numeric',
      numericFormat: {
        pattern: '0.0000'
      }
    },
    {
      data: 'units',
      type: 'text'
    },
    {
      data: 'asOf',
      type: 'date',
      dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    },
    {
      data: 'date1',
      type: 'text',
    },
    {
      data: 'date2',
      type: 'text',
    },
    {
      data: 'onedChng',
      type: 'numeric',
      numericFormat: {
        pattern: '0.00%'
      }
    }
  ],
  stretchH: 'all',
  width: 805,
  autoWrapRow: true,
  height: 487,
  maxRows: 22,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: [
    'ID',
    'Country',
    'Code',
    'Currency',
    'Level',
    'Units',
    'Date',
    'Date',
    'Date',
    'Change'
  ],
  columnSorting: {
    indicator: true
  },
  autoColumnSize: {
    samplingRatio: 23
  },
  language: 'en-US'
};
var hot = new Handsontable(hotElement, hotSettings);
```